# Trying to run Mozilla XUL demos

Tags: xul

I've downloaded [the xul demos](http://www.hevanet.com/acorbin/xul/top.xul) from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL), a single file called "top.xul", but when I open it on Firefox it says the file for each demo is missing.. Is it just here? Do someone succeed to run the demos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top.xul file links to other .xul files.  To run it all locally you would need to download them locally.

e.g. you would need to download http://www.hevanet.com/acorbin/xul/layout.xul .

View the source of top.xul to see which other files it links to.

Or, simply view the example from the page you linked to without downloading it.

Comment: ok, I forgot I was running on Chrome, so it was downloaded instead of started online.. XD Thanks!

Comment: Right, that's certainly not cross-browser.  In fact, viewing it that way will be disabled in Firefox 4 I believe. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_remote_xul)